# TR level styling

Tags: html, css

I have a `table` and I want to style at `tr` level.  This does not work on IE7 if I apply the style directly to the `tr`.

What's the best way to go about styling the `table` so I get a line across all rows but have no line at the very top or at the very bottom.

So basically, the table should look something like this

```
col1 col2 col3
--------------
col1 col2 col3
--------------
col1 col2 col3
--------------
col1 col2 col3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this without the `:last-child` selector, in a way that is also compatible with IE7. And of course without JavaScript:

```
table tr + tr td {
    border-top: 1px black solid;
}
```

Actually you are using the *top* border to draw a line, taking advantage of the fact that the `tr + tr` selector will match all rows except the first one.

[**See it in action**](http://jsfiddle.net/7VeWL/).

Comment: @Jon, I can't seem to get it to work.  They lines don't show up in IE7.  I even checked the script in jsfiddle and they are not showing up for me.  http://jsfiddle.net/7VeWL/5/

Comment: @oshirowanen: My own example works fine for me. I 'm trying it with IE 9, in IE7 standards mode (selected from the Developer Tools Window). Choosing Quirks mode makes it not work (as expected). Maybe the problem is with the HTML you are generating, or maybe your page puts IE in Quirks mode. In any case it's impossible to tell from your example because you are dynamically creating elements and it's not obvious at all what is going on exactly.

Comment: I've stripped the example script: http://jsfiddle.net/7VeWL/8/.  I thought I was using standards mode instead of quirks mode?  I've just checked the html and it is producing strict xhtml.

Comment: @oshirowanen: That page renders as intended with IE9 in IE7 standards mode for me.

Comment: How can I set the html to use standards mode?

Comment: Ensure you are using the appropriate doctype, or use the HTML5 one <!DOCTYPE html>

Answer (score 1):

To get a border on the bottom of each row:

```
table tr td {
border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Then you would need to use some javascript to change the style of the last one, or use css which is probably not supported in IE6/7

```
table tr:last-child td {
border-bottom: none;
}
```

example: http://jsbin.com/ezolur

Comment: A good alternative for IE7 support is Jon's answer, or if you can get a class onto the last TR then you'd be laughing.

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS2 selectors:

```
table#mytable tr{
    border-bottom:1px solid black;
}
table#mytable tr:last-child{
    border-bottom:none;
}
```

Comment: Indeed, it's not supported before IE9 [See here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024(v=vs.85).aspx). The solution for IE is the tr+tr as proposed by Jon.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<tr>
<td colspan="3"><hr/></td></tr>
```

Comment: I can't use this method as I have 3 columns in the table.

Comment: should work. because it has colspan="3" should work with 3 columns

Comment: that's what the colspan="3" does. If you add this TR between the rows it'll add a row where it's single field represents a normal 3 fields.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the last-child selector:

have a look at this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/SGfQy/

EDIT:
can you change the html of your table, you could put your first row in the thead, and the rest of your rows in the tbody,  and then use

```
table tbody tr td{
     border-top:1px solid red;   
}
```

updated fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/SGfQy/1/